# How to close dynamically generated dropdown on clicking on the body using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am developing web application in angularjs. On top right corner i have one drop-down box and this will become active only after user logged in. I have scenario where user clicks on dropdown and once he clicks anywhere on the page i want to close the dropdown. I am struggling to fix this from long time. I have created plunker in order to understand what problem i am facing properly.

> ```
> `https://plnkr.co/edit/4RjrBDHE6mmxofwRovfB?p=preview`
> ```

May i get some help here to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation`. You can add the following code to make it work

**HTML**:

```
<div class="user" ng-click="OpenDropdown($event)">
   <h1>Dropdown</h1>
   <div class="user-dropdown" ng-show="dp" id="ProfileDropdown"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.OpenDropdown = function(event) {
    if ($scope.dp === false || $scope.dp === undefined) {
        $scope.dp = true;
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        $scope.dp = false;
    }
};
window.onclick = function() {
    if ($scope.dp) {
        $scope.dp = false;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

**Working Demo**: https://plnkr.co/edit/6h91NXc4S8zD7jAbOz33?p=preview

If you want to use a **directive** to achieve this, check out this **[solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/XhhF2VH1YWf0QDmLr7oa?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been struggling since long time.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a directive . Glad that I could be of help :)

Comment: Which is the better solution? Thank you for giving me multiple answers

Comment: I would suggest to go with directive as $event.stopPropagation may break the flow of execution of the page