# how to hide the div if clicked outside the div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

> For the notifications I want that my div will be hidden if clicked outside of it
>   [plunker code link](http://plnkr.co/edit/b0J5401IXDW5f36plLv3?p=info)
>   the html code is

```
<div ng-hide="notification" ng-click="notifications($event);"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div ng-hide="notifyData">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="noti in newNotificationarray">
            <div class="notifymsg">{{noti.msg}}</div>
            <div class="notifytitle">
                <a href="#">{{noti.title}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="notifyName">{{noti.cName}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>                                
</div>
```

> the js code in controller is

```
$scope.notifications=function(event){
    $scope.notifyData=!($scope.notifyData);          
    event.stopPropagation();
};

window.onclick = function(){
    if ($scope.notifyData) {
        $scope.notifyData=false;          
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

> If I do it without using "event.stopPropagation();" then the div hide when clicked anywhere on the screen and also on the notification div

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364873/how-to-close-dynamically-generated-dropdown-on-clicking-on-the-body-using-angula/45365073#45365073

Comment: @alex the duplicate example do not use any ng-hide or ng-show directives, and i used them so that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @alex here is the example in this code the div does not hide when clicked outside of it https://plnkr.co/edit/b0J5401IXDW5f36plLv3?p=info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close dynamically generated dropdown on clicking on the body using angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364873/how-to-close-dynamically-generated-dropdown-on-clicking-on-the-body-using-angula)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to inject the window service. You should do it this way so that it can be mocked in your tests.

Also, **update the logic in onclick handler** for `window`.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  ...
  $window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!$scope.notifyData) {
      $scope.notifyData = true;
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  }

}]);
```

Comment: thanks but this code doesn't solve my problem as it hide the div(notifyData) when clicked on it and i want to hide it when clicked outside of it