# Show and Hide a <div> inside an ng-repeat with 'dirPagination' (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, dirpagination

In this very site I've seen this question many times, but none of them works for me because of two things: I need the div to toggle when clicking the "options" button, but also to hide when clicking outside of the div; and I need it to work with dirPagination.

I saw [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364873/how-to-close-dynamically-generated-dropdown-on-clicking-on-the-body-using-angula/45365073#45365073), it works fine but with one problem I just can't solve: it shows ALL the hidden divs at the same time, instead of only showing the one I clicked.

Here's my code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <!-- pagination -->
  <dir-pagination-controls
    max-size="7"
    direction-links="true"
    boundary-links="true">
  </dir-pagination-controls>

  <ul>
      <li dir-paginate="report in reports | itemsPerPage:4">
          <a href="#" ng-click="showOptions($event)">Options</a>
          <h3>{{report.Title}}</h3>
          <div class="options" ng-show="dp">
              <p>These are some options</p>
          </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

And the JS to show the options:

```
//options div
$scope.showOptions = function(event){
    if($scope.dp === false || $scope.dp === undefined) {
        $scope.dp = true;
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        $scope.dp = false;
    }
};
window.onclick = function(){
    if($scope.dp){
        $scope.dp = false;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

I've made a Plunker in case you wanna se it in action: [my Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/YM3ro1R1wP70oSTNs1Vl)

Can somebody help me with this issue? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a separate variable for each div you want to show. You could add the dp attribute to the report. There is no need to loop over the reports to hide them. You can just keep track of the currently visible report and hide it when another one is toggled.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<li dir-paginate="report in reports | itemsPerPage:4">
    <a href="#" ng-click="showOptions($event, report)">Options</a>
    <h3>{{report.Title}}</h3>
    <div class="options" ng-show="report.dp">
      <p>These are some options</p>
    </div>
 </li>
```

and JavaScript

```
var visibleReport;
$scope.showOptions = function(event, report){
  if (report == visibleReport) {
    report.dp = !report.dp;
  }
  else {
    if (visibleReport) visibleReport.dp = false;
    report.dp = true;
  }
  visibleReport = report
  event.stopPropagation();
};
window.onclick = function(){
  if (visibleReport)  visibleReport.dp = false;
  visibleReport = null;
  $scope.$apply();
};
```

Here is a working plunker https://next.plnkr.co/edit/sWLxBGlF8D22nvYp?preview

Comment: This is great, only I also need the options to also toggle, but thanks is really helpful

Comment: @SoulEeater The options also toggle now

Comment: It works perfectly fine, even better! though it displays an error sometimes in the console..

Comment: It says "cannot set property 'dp' of null at window.onclick" everytime you click outside of the "options button"

Comment: I've fixed the code.  I'll update the plunker later.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new boolean property on your reports array , for example `show`

```
 var reports = [
        {
          "ID":1,
          "Title":"Report 1",
          "Show":false
        },
        {
          "ID":2,
          "Title":"Report 2",
           "Show":false
        }
]
```

Apply the property in to ng-show and also pass the current **report** scope object in to **showOptions** method to write the logic for hide and show.

```
     <li dir-paginate="report in reports | itemsPerPage:4">
                      <a href="#" ng-click="showOptions($event,report)">Options</a>
                      <h3>{{report.Title}}</h3>
                      <div class="options" ng-show="report.Show">
                          <p>These are some options</p>
                      </div>
                  </li>


        $scope.showOptions = function(event,report){
              report.Show=!report.Show;
/*you can iterate through each reports and change show to false if the clicked report id not equal to report id , Angular JS will automatically update the scope in to the view*/
     reports.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (item.ID !== report.ID) {
              item.Show = false;
            }
          });
                if($scope.dp === false || $scope.dp === undefined) {
                    $scope.dp = true;
                    event.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                    $scope.dp = false;
                }
            };
```

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/hnhWMrgR3GMtVcES

Comment: The thing is I need the div to hide when you "click outside of it".
With your example when I open another one the last one is still opened, I need to open only the one I clicked and hide the others..

Comment: @SoulEeater Updated the plunker , I hope that is you are looking for